# How random are the dungeon map variations? Are there predictable differences between difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've run through the game on Normal, Nightmare, and Hell (and parts of Inferno) on non-hardcore and feel like I've seen the same or very similar dungeon layouts throughout regardless of character, level, solo/multiplayer, etc.

Conversely, on hardcore I've never seen the same dungeon twice. I've also seen sections of dungeon (appearance-wise, etc.) that I never saw on non-hardcore.

Are there discrete sections of dungeon that only spawn if you are in hardcore mode? And if so, are there certain events, lore, etc. that must be done on hardcore?

Answer (score 5):

Hardcore is exactly the same game as softcore, and does not change any abilities, bosses, enemies, or dungeons.

If you notice a difference or trend, it's simply due to random chance.